# Using TabWidget.setDividerDrawable()?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

Has anyone had any success with `TabWidget.setDivider()`? I'm not sure it does what I'm assuming: gives you a chance to supply a drawable to be drawn between each tab instance?

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.dividerDrawable);
```

this does not appear to do anything. Looking at the tab drawable resources in the android project shows that the dividers are actually drawn into the tab images themselves - is this supposed to work or is it not supported?

Comment: I'm having this problem myself, did you come to a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Call that before you set the content of the tabs.Or It would crash.
[similar answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705346/dividers-between-tabwidgets)